# Play sound when changing checkbox state in Org Mode?

Tags: org-mode, evil, doom

Context: [Org Mode](https://orgmode.org/).

I want to play a unique audio file when entering each of these three checkbox states: `[ ]` `[-]` `[X]`.

So one audio file when entering `[ ]` state, a different one for `[-]`, etc.

Example document:

```
+ [ ] Foo
    + [ ] ?
+ [ ] Bar
+ [ ] ...
```

How?

---

Pressing `C-h k RET` when on checkbox gives:

```
+org/dwim-at-point is an autoloaded and interactive function defined
in org.el.

Signature
(+org/dwim-at-point &optional ARG)

Documentation
Do-what-I-mean at point.

If on a:
- checkbox list item or todo heading: toggle it.
- citation: follow it
- headline: cycle ARCHIVE subtrees, toggle latex fragments and inline images in
  subtree; update statistics cookies/checkboxes and ToCs.
- clock: update its time.
- footnote reference: jump to the footnote's definition
- footnote definition: jump to the first reference of this footnote
- timestamp: open an agenda view for the time-stamp date/range at point.
- table-row or a TBLFM: recalculate the table's formulas
- table-cell: clear it and go into insert mode. If this is a formula cell,
  recaluclate it instead.
- babel-call: execute the source block
- statistics-cookie: update it.
- src block: execute it
- latex fragment: toggle it.
- link: follow it
- otherwise, refresh all inline images in current tree.

Key Bindings
evil-org-mode-map <normal-state> <return>
evil-org-mode-map <normal-state> RET

References
+org/dwim-at-point is unused in org.el.

Find all references Functions used by +org/dwim-at-point

Debugging
Enable edebug Enable tracing
Disassemble Forget

Source Code
;; Defined in ~/.config/emacs/modules/lang/org/autoload/org.el
;;;###autoload
(defun +org/dwim-at-point (&optional arg)
  "Do-what-I-mean at point.

...

Symbol Properties
event-symbol-element-mask
  (+org/dwim-at-point 0)
event-symbol-elements
  (+org/dwim-at-point)
function-history
  ("/home/user/.config/emacs/modules/lang/org/autoload/org.el"
   (autoload "~/.config/emacs/modules/lang/org/autoload/org"
     ("/home/user/.config/emacs/.local/etc/@/init.29.elc" . 180542)
     t nil))
modifier-cache
  ((0 . +org/dwim-at-point))
```

Comment: Are you typing the characters or are you using `C-c C-c` somewhere on the line to change the state of a checkbox? If the latter, it will be relatively easy; if the former, it still can be done I think but it will be much more complicated.

Comment: @NickD I'm just using the enter/return character.

Comment: To change the state of the checkbox? I don't think that works - does it? Where exactly do you press it? Inside a checkbox? When I do that, it just breaks the line at that point.

Comment: @NickD Maybe it's because I'm on Doom Emacs and Evil-Mode? I press enter/return anywhere on the checkbox or right before or after it, and I'm not in "input mode".

Comment: OK - maybe. What does `C-h k RET` say when you do it at the same place where it switches the checkbox state?

Comment: @NickD I've added the output of that to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspecting [the +org/dwim-at-point function](https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs/blob/7984cd8e0fee24738fe911365738f2fe634854bb/modules/lang/org/autoload/org.el#L280), we find that it uses `org-toggle-checkbox`.

Therefore, we can simply advise that function to add the play sound functionality as follows:

```lisp
(defun org-toggle-checkbox-ad (_)
  (org-at-item-checkbox-p)
  (play-sound-file (pcase (match-string 1)
             ("[ ]" "path/to/sound/file1.wav")
             ("[X]" "path/to/sound/file2.wav")
             ("[-]" "path/to/sound/file3.wav"))))

(advice-add 'org-toggle-checkbox :after #'org-toggle-checkbox-ad)
```

Like in the `+org/dwim-at-point` we use `(org-at-item-checkbox-p)` so that to simply obtain the checkbox (string) using `match-string`.

Unfortunately, I can't get `play-sound-file` to work here, as I don't know how to configure the sound device, but if I could, then [it would only play `.wav` or `.au` files](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sound-Output.html).

However, we can simply call a command line application to play the sounds, e.g. `ogg123` to play an `.ogg` file as follows:

```lisp
(defun org-toggle-checkbox-ad (_)
  (org-at-item-checkbox-p)
  (call-process "ogg123" nil nil nil
        (pcase (match-string 1)
          ("[ ]" "/path/to/sound1.ogg")
          ("[X]" "/path/to/sound2.ogg")
          ("[-]" "/path/to/sound3.ogg"))))
```

When using the code in the second block, don't forget to additionally advise the `org-toggle-checkbox` function.